# SpringFramework custom binding with type parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to bind custom Object/Interface implementations to my controller.

```
class Form{
    private Action action;
    // setter/getter
}

interface Action{}

class Action1 implements Action{}

class Action2 implements Action{}


@Controller
class ActionController{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String action(Form form){
      form.getAction(); // this should be an instance of Action1 or Action2
    }
}
```

To determine if it's an Action1 or Action2, I would like to add a type parameter to the HTML form.

```
<input name="form.action.type" value="1" />
```

is there something like this already available or does anyone know how to implement this.

I already had a look at PropertyEditors, but as far as i can tell, you only get one field as string and it seems you can't access any other property.
If possible I'm looking for an easier way than creating my own HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Comment: There are certainly ways to meet your requirement. But without knowing what other fields the form contains and what `Action` looks like it is hard to give you a more precise advice than *look at PropertyEditor and Converter*

Comment: The form and the Action Object got a lot of properties. Action1 differs from Action2 in all properties (excluding type). Action1 or Action2 may even contain more Objects with type fields.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do that exactly. When a controller declares a `ModelAttribute` parameter, Spring first creates an empty object and set its parameters or the parameters of its subobjects. So it will have to create an Action object before analyzing the form.action.type parameter.

One way to to it would be to use a default `Action` implementation that will be able to accept directly all the form parameters. Then the getter would generate the proper `Action` type.

```
private class ActionDefault {
    // parameters and setters to store all form fields at appropriate level
}

class Form {
    Action action = null;
    ActionDefault actionDefault = new ActionDefault();

    Action getAction() {
        if (action == null) {
            // generates proper Action object and affects it to action
        }
        return action;
    }
    // getter and setter for actionDefault;
}
```